# commands in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command

I have the following code by it isn't working any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using `lambda` function

```
login_button = Button(root, text="Click here to enter data", command=lambda:[main_menu(),apending_to_text_file()])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working, the apending_to_text_file part works but not the main_menu part

Comment: try with `main_menu()` round brackets @Katie010203

Comment: @Katie010203 You can accept it as an answer if you found it helpful

Comment: A function would be much easier to maintain and debug than a complex lambda.

Answer (score 2):

This parameter will not accept two functions.
The best way for you to solve this is to create a function that performs all other functions.

```
def main_menu():
    pass


def apending_to_text_file():
    pass


def commands():
    main_menu()
    apending_to_text_file()


login_button = Button(
    root, text="Click here to enter data",
    command=commands
)
```

Comment: I think this is a much better solution than crafting a hard-to-read and hard-to-debug lambda.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here. `and` is a logical and, so you can't use it like that.

Second, you are calling your second function with the parentheses instead of passing the function itself. This means that you are passing the return value of a function as the command. So if we had a function

```
def my_func():
    return 'hello'
```

passing in `command = my_func` will make the button call my_func(). If you try to pass in `command = my_func()`, you end up passing in the string `hello` which doesn't make sense.

Third, a solution would be to wrap both functions in a separate function. To do this inline, you can use a lambda function that calls both functions (in this case, you would want the parentheses). Or you can just define this function separately and call both of the functions you want.

Here are the examples:

```
def on_button_submit():
    main_menu()
    appending_to_text_file()
```

So then you an use this on_button_submit as the command for your button.

Or use a lambda function. Here is a quick example of how lambda function would work:

```
def func1():
  print('in func1')

def func2():
  print('in func2')

x = lambda : (func1(), func2())
x()
```

So you can use the following as your button command:

```
lambda : (main_menu(), appending_to_text_file())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am a bit confused on how to do this

Comment: Sure, I'll give some examples